# Unable to add secure web service reference

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm not able to add web reference for a secure web service which is located at https://connect.instamed.com/Healthcare/Service.asmx.

I'm able to authenticate *and connect* to the service using browser.

Currently, I'm following the below steps to add the service reference:

- Right click project
- Click add service reference
- Click Advance
- Click Add Web reference
- Input URL and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Enter credentials upon prompt
- See things happening...

After entering credentials, I'm getting the below error:

[image]

This is not allowing me to move things further. Any idea to consume this kind of web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This URL needs authentication, so it is difficult to replicate here.

However, [you can use .WSDL file to add reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017087/2404470).

Comment: updated my question. Yes, I'm able to access the service.

Comment: Can you access the WSDL file?

Comment: Yes, I have the `.wsdl` file.

Comment: I mean, can you get the file from the following link: https://connect.instamed.com/Healthcare/Service.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Hi @KarlGjertsen -  I'm able to add the service using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10017087/2404470) method.

Comment: It's hard to replicate without the username and password.